# Android: Action button icons always appear in overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Action items always  appear in overlay. Here is the code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event_black_18dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

and in the main activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Shouldn't the first item appear on the action bar because of "app:showAsAction="always" ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this inside your item ,to display in Action bar

`app:showAsAction="always"`

When you dont want to display item in Action bar

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

Try this piece of code , instead of your creating Option Menu

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I already use that in my item, as you can see from the above code. Also tried "getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);" but doesn't help either.

Comment: you can give your first item as app:showAsAction="ifRoom" ,to display in the Action bar @bazera

Comment: I've corrected it. I've just changed "app" with "android". It gave me an error, but I ignored it. Launched the app and everything was working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is for **fragments**

custom namespace will prevent showAsAction from showing. so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
    android:title="@string/action_create_order"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_event_black_18dp"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: No, it's not for fragments, it's for main activity.